# Manifest.json not being fetched in Chrome

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps

I have fetched `manifest.json` properly, as per the guide on web.dev.
I even copied the format of `manifest.json` from site if mine is incorrect.
Firefox recognizes `manifest.json`. It tells me the details as well.
But Chrome dosen't. Cant see it in applications tab.
I tried deleting sw.js and remaking it, still no use.

> I am using next.js 14.

Comment: Did you check the network tab of devtools? Can you include the exact `<link>` tag for manifest included in your html page? Can you try requesting the manifest url directly and see what happens in chrome?

Comment: I am typing this: <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
Link: view-source:https://nishweb.tech/manifest.json.
Manifest.json is in network tab of firefox, but not in chrome